# How can I dependency injection MediaRecorder with Hilt in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I hope to dependency injection `MediaRecorder` object with Hilt in Android Studio.

But the Code A get the error  *'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types* .

And the Code B get the error  *Dagger does not support injection into private fields* .

The Code C can be compiled, but it's not what I need.  I need to define `mRecorder` as nullable, so I can use `mRecorder = null` to release it.

How can I fix the Code A?

**Code A**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel()
{
    @Inject lateinit var mRecorder: MediaRecorder?

}

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMediaRecorder(): MediaRecorder {
        return  MediaRecorder()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel()
{
    @Inject var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? =null

}

...
```

**Code C**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel()
{
    @Inject  lateinit  var mRecorder: MediaRecorder

}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do property injection if you don't have reference to your component/injector object. You may want to add the recorder as constructor parameter.

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(private val recorder: MediaRecorder
): ViewModel()
```

Alternatively, if you really want to make your recorder nullable you can utilize `Provider`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(private val recorderProvider: Provider<MediaRecorder>
): ViewModel(){

    private val recorder : MediaRecorder? = null

   init {
        recorder = recorderProvider.get() 
    }

}
```

For releasing your media recorder use `mediaRecorder.release()` function.

Comment: Thanks! what are differents between my Code C and your code `class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(private val recorder: MediaRecorder...` ?

Comment: There are three types of injecton: constructor, field and method, you are using field injection in CodeC without having component to perform the field/prop injection.

Comment: Thanks! `class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(private val recorder: MediaRecorder? ...` can be compiled. is it correct code?

Comment: And more, I can't understand fully what `You can't do property injection if you don't have reference to your component/injector object.`  means, could you tell me? Thanks!

Comment: You code `private val recorder : MediaRecorder? = null` can't be compiled, does it shoud be `private var recorder : MediaRecorder? = null` ?